# do setting the max_length to a very large value consume extra space?

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I have a field in the model,

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

and the data entered is,

```
name='abc'
```

the django model's `max_length` is set to 2000 while the entered data is only of length 3,
Does the `max_length` reserves space for 2000 characters in the database table per object? after the model object is saved, does the space is freed up?

Do setting up higher `max_length` increase the size of database if the number of objects on database is several thousands or millions?

Database is postgres

Comment: You can use `manage.py sqlmigrate` to inspect the sql yourself: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate-app-label-migrationname

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CharField` will be represented by a `character varying(max_length)` in PostgreSQL.

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-character.html):

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1.

So, the disk space the string will take up is dependent on it's length + a small overhead, not on the max length of the field.

Using a higher `max_length` will not increase the disk space used by the db.

Comment: Just to note, this answer is true for PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server. If you choose to use a non-relational or other database, the same may not be true.